# Translate SQL query to Ruby on Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I need to convert a relatively simple query to display a total quiz average for a given user in a table set up in Rails/HAML. We have users take quizzes, record the scores, and display the average per quiz. We now want to total average of all quizzes. Easy:

```
SELECT (ROUND(AVG(`score`*100), 1)) FROM `quiz_results` WHERE `user_id`=$user
```

The results need to display in a table cell that is already set up, but I cannot figure this out.

Perhaps this line will help. It's pre-existing code that calculates the average of a particular quiz for that user:

```
%td.separate="#{(((lesson.quiz_results.average('score', :conditions => "user_id = #{@user.id}")) * 100).to_i)}%"
```

I have Rails 2.3.x.

Comment: That's an actual line in your Haml file? There's a Rails 2.6? (Re: Diamond Pen homepage, "Philosophy" typo--maybe add ooooone more cross-check.)

Comment: Yes, and typo. Rails 2.3.x. Fixed in OP.

Comment: Re. Philosophy - thanks for the eagle eyes. ::embarrassed::

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as i can see now - all you need is to remove particular quiz restriction, which is imposed by association usage `lesson.quiz_results` - instead of it just use model class, which is most likely `QuizResult`.

And, also, there is tiny bug in your existing code - `.to_i` will rounding down, you should use `.round`. See the difference:

```
irb(main):002:0> 1.6.to_i
=> 1
irb(main):003:0> 1.6.round
=> 2
```

So, full code should be:

```
(QuizResult.average('score', :conditions => "user_id = #{@user.id}") * 100).round
```

(I also removed some unnecessary brackets)

Comment: Have this in the HAML file: %td (QuizResult.average('score', :conditions => "user_id = #{@user.id}") * 100).round  But it's showing as (quiz_results.average('score', :conditions => "user_id = 4349") * 100).round  Tried add #{} around it, no luck. Thanks though

Comment: Blah. I'm an idiot. This worked:  %td="#{(QuizResult.average('score', :conditions => "user_id = #{@user.id}") * 100).round}%"  Thanks so much for your help!